# How to check if a list contains a specific words which is part of another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am new to python this may be something small but I am finding it difficult on how to get output for this

I have below list "sgList" which I want to check if it contains any of the specific words which is another list "checkforstrings" if yes then return true otherwise false

```
sgList   = ['Sensitive-ce-Public-TF_', 'cb-access', 'convc-service']

checkforstrings = ["-Public-", "-Private-", "-Protected-"]
```

in the above case this should return true coz '-Public-' is present in 'Sensitive-ce-Public-TF_'

I know how to find a specific word in list but this may either in the starting/ending or middle so not sure how to check this
Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to wrap a generator expression in `any`. The idea is we iterate over each string in `checkforstrings` and see if it's in any string in `sgList`:

```py
out = any(s in sg for s in checkforstrings for sg in sgList)
```

Output:

```py
True
```

Comment: thank you this is helpful. How to make sure that this ignores any case, upper case/lower case should not matter if the word exists then return true. Do both the lists need to be converted to lowercase and then compare?

Comment: @AjayMisra you can call `lower` in the strings, so instead of `s in sg`, use `s.lower() in sg.lower()`

Answer (score -2):

You can use the operator `in`.

`If '-Public-' in 'Sensitive-ce-Public-TF`'

Would return true.

Comment: But he wants to check for any of the strings in `checkforstrings`, not just `-Public-`.

Comment: And also any of the strings in `sgList`.